# xts - return a list of missing rows and calculate % of missing rows

Tags: r, xts

Is there a straightforward way to return a list of missing rows in an xts? Below produces an xts and for this example it is intentionally missing 2 rows.

Further on, when having the list (of missing rows), is it possible to calculate the % of missing rows (e.g. 2 rows are missing where the total should be 100 rows = 2% or rows are missing).

```
# load dependent packages
library(xts)

# create a set of test data to be used
d <- as.POSIXct(c("2017/01/01 09:00:00", "2017/01/01 09:02:00",
              "2017/01/01 09:02:00", "2017/01/01 09:05:00"))
o = c(98.00, 97.67, 98.00, 98.10) # for "open" data
h = c(99.71, 98.97, 99.71, 99.41) # for "high" data
l = c(96.81, 96.86, 96.81, 97.70) # for "low" data
c = c(97.67, 98.67, 97.67, 98.83) # for "close" data
v = c(1000, 22000, 1000, 50000) # for "volume" data
a = c(1000, 22000, 1000, 50000) # for "adjusted" data

# create a dataframe
mydf1 <- data.frame("date" = d, "open" = o, "high" = h, "low" = l,
                "close" = c, "volume" = v, "adjusted" = a)

# create an xts based on dataframe mydf1
myxts1 <- xts(mydf1[,-1], order.by = mydf1$date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposal for the task.

Calculate a vector including all times based on the present times in the `xts` object:

```
all_times <- seq(min(time(myxts1)), max(time(myxts1)),
                 by = min(diff(time(myxts1))))
```

Create vector including missing times:

```
missing_times <- all_times[!all_times %in% time(myxts1)]

missing_times
# [1] "2017-01-01 09:01:00 CET" "2017-01-01 09:04:00 CET"
```

Percentage of missing times:

```
length(missing_times) / length(all_times) * 100
# [1] 33.33333
```

Comment: It works really great with the xts data above. Using real downloaded OHLC data into xts format sometimes gives this error:
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : invalid '(to - from)/by' in 'seq'. 
It seems that it is the "all_times" line part: by = min(diff(time(xts10))

Comment: @Toolbox The example should resemble the characteristics of the original data as close as possible.

Comment: For some unknown reason the solution works up until 22 xts lines. having 23 xts lines produces above error.

Comment: @Toolbox Can you provide an example for which the solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Hohestein I updated above xts data. If your just run it you will see the error. Seems the solution you suggested breaks when the first duplicate date/timestamps is present. Can an expansion of your script handle duplicates or should I secure that those are being removed, prior to running your solution?

Comment: @Toolbox Is the distance between timesteps always 1 minute?

Comment: @Hogenstein In these tests I am trying between 1 min up to 5 min to find the optimal stability in download data. Later on I plan to connect the minute resolution settting to Shiny and then I will have (1/5/15/30 min, 1h, 3h, etc).

Comment: @Toolbox How do you define missing rows?

Comment: @Hogenstein when there are timestamps that are missing in date (left column). If the time stamp resolution is 5 min, a missing timestamp would create a gap, thus causing the 2 nearest line (1 above, 1 below the missing line) to have 10 minutes in between. Theoretically a timestamp could be missing both on the 1st line and the last line. This can happen if you define the time range and comparing with the downloaded data in xts you find first or last line missing.